# How to add a pre-loader to a django web site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, preloader

i had made a web app in django that takes some input through form,
performs some long computation in django views, store the results in context and renders the results in other template.In between taking submitting input and displaying result i want to display a loading page ,but i didn't found any resource that could explain me in some simple step by step manner.

Any resource or reference will be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this would be using an AJAX request for submitting the input. As soon as the request is made, you show the loader, and when its finished (success callback) you redirect to the other view or show the results instead of the loader.

Step by step:

- setup ajax request that collects all the user input (frontend)
- show a div with the loader as soon as user submits form (frontend)
- submit form to a url (that is connected to a view) that catches the post request and handles the input (backend)
- return the results of that view as a `JsonResponse` (backend)
- render the results using the success callback of your ajax request (frontend)
- hide the loader div in that callback (frontend)

Comment: thanks @Vincent . Is their any tutorial that i can follow. It's difficult for me to follow up with this.

Comment: @Razeun you could look at: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html. A bit older django version, but the steps are the same